Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 on D drive is invisible
I have 2 M2 SSDs in my PC, a 500GB one (C: drive), which hosts the Windows 11 boot, etc. and a 1TB one, which I have partitioned into 2 spaces of 500GB each approximately (D: and F: drives).
I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the D: drive, however after the installation was complete and I had to restart the PC, I can't get it to identify the D: drive and boot from it. When I boot into UEFI mode and try to change the boot order, I only see the 1TB disk as a whole, and when I boot from it I get greeted with a message saying Reboot and select proper boot device or insert Boot Media in selected boot device and press a key. I tried EasyBCD, but it won't identify that I have a Linux installation, no matter which drive I install it on. Here is a photo of the disk partitioning in Windows Disk Management.


You need to give the partition the "boot" flag (sometimes also called "bootable"). Probably you can right-click on it and see some Properties pane on which you can tick "boot," or something like that.

@Zatrapilla i tried both using the Disk Management tool and though the Terminal in admin mode. The option is not clickable, and when i try to do it using terminal it says:
The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk.
The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks.

Standard rule is use Windows tools for Windows and Linux tools for Linux. Windows cannot create Linux partitions and does not allow boot from external drives. If external drive empty make sure it is gpt, not MBR(msdos) and create ESP for UEFI boot or bios_grub for BIOS boot. Most system are UEFI. Live installer in live mode had gparted to create and manage partitions. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs, If you have M.2 ports system is new enough for UEFI installs.
